# anime.js hover on every instance of class

Tags: javascript, hover, anime.js

Im trying to get this function to run on every instance of a button my site. Please help :)

```js
// Button Hover
var buttonEl = document.querySelector('button');

function animateButton(scale, duration) {
  anime.remove(buttonEl);
  anime({
    targets: buttonEl,
    scale: scale,
    duration: duration,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
  });
}

function enterButton() { animateButton(1.05, 100) };
function leaveButton() { animateButton(1.0, 75) };

buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', enterButton, false);
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', leaveButton, false);
```

```html
<button class="restart">Hover Me</button>
```

Comment: The declaration of anime is missing here..

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I'm pretty new to this stuff. Thanks!